# How to navigate up/down using keyboard home keys in Eclipse's suggestions pop up window?

Tags: eclipse

When Eclipse shows a popup for code completion, how do you change the highlighted option using the keyboard home keys? Currently, if the thing I want is third or fourth on the list of suggestions, I have to use the mouse to select it, or use the arrow keys. Is there a way to use the keyboard home keys/ shortcuts with ctrl/alt to do this?

Comment: I have the same 'problem'. If I use the arrow keys the 'cursor' in the code is moved, not the selection in completion pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow keys always work for me. Can you be little more specific as to what perspective, editor, etc?

I get a code completion popup when I press Ctrl + 1 in the Java editor. From then on, I can use the arrow keys to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to select from the code completion menu by `X` for up and `Y` for down. Go to Preferences > Keys and bind the commands `Line Up` and `Line Down` to `X` and `Y`, respectively. Make sure that in the `When` drop-down you select `In Windows`.

Note that after the settings are applied, `X` (`Y`) also makes the cursor go one line up (down) in the source editor. Personally, I use `X = Ctrl+P` and `Y = Ctrl+N` which means I can navigate lines and select entries from the code completion menu without lifting my hands off the keyboard.

Unfortunately, these bindings don't work with other pop-up lists in Eclipse, e.g. quick outline (`Ctrl+O`) or quick access (`Ctrl+3`). I'd love to find out how to bind these too.